# Liferay page to auto-refresh?

Tags: liferay

We would like, for example, to have a page that displays a blog to refresh from time to time when a person leaves the page open.

Does anyone know of a quick and easy way to get a liferay page to auto-refresh at some interval? (preferably without having to create/modify a theme).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dont want to modify theme than just add new Web Contetn Display portlet to your page and create/select article that has only

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",10000);
</script>
```

as content. Be sure to go to source view of your rich test editr field (if you use it).

Change 10000 (milliseconds) to your need.

Comment: make sure that this does not apply to the "add blog entry" mode of the page. I'd rather not put it on the blog page in the theme - rather into the blogs portlet itself. Of course, the ideal version is to have the blog portlet automatically updating itself - granted, this is a lot more complex than the three lines given, but it's also a lot clearer.